# Rangebar series not centered

Tags: c#, charts, series, microsoft-chart-controls

I am working with a RangeBar Chart in a c# form app. When I add the series to the chart they do no line up correctly. When I change the "DrawSideBySide=false" it works fine, but I need some of the series to be side by side.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

My code is just a List of Series being populated and then those series being added to a chart.

I loop through this populating series and adding them to a series list.
Populating-

```
double yplot1 = (double)user.Projects[i].StartDate.ToOADate();
double yplot2 = (double)user.Projects[i].EndDate.ToOADate();
// Use a different series for each datapoint
Series seriesInstance = new Series();
//seriesInstance.Name = user.Name;
seriesInstance.Label = user.Projects[i].Name + " - " + (user.Projects[i].AllocationPercent * 100).ToString() + "%";
seriesInstance.AxisLabel = user.Name;

seriesInstance.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
// Have a start and end date so plotting 2 points on the y-axis
seriesInstance.YValuesPerPoint = 2;

//seriesInstance.CustomProperties = "DrawSideBySide=true";
//seriesInstance["PixelPointWidth"] = "200";
seriesInstance["MinPixelPointWidth"] = "150";

int xordinal = j;
seriesInstance.IsXValueIndexed = false;
seriesInstance.Points.AddXY(xordinal, yplot1, yplot2);
/*seriesInstance.Points[0].ToolTip = someTipText;
seriesInstance.Points[0].Color = resourceColor;
seriesInstance.Points[0].AxisLabel = xlabel;*/
seriesList.Add(seriesInstance);
```

Then I add all the series in the list to the chart

```
foreach (Series plotSeries in seriesList)
{
chart1.Series.Add(plotSeries);
}
// Force x-axis to show each task or resource

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

// Set y-axis to show each day of the month
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
ChartArea chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
chartArea1.AxisX.IsReversed = true;
// Set other y-axis properties
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 5;

chartArea1.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
chartArea1.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
if ((lastDate - firstDate).TotalDays < 60)
{
chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
}
else if (((lastDate - firstDate).TotalDays > 60) && ((lastDate - firstDate).TotalDays < 365))
{
chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
}
else
{
chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
}
// Set the y-axis labels
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = firstDate.AddDays(-1).ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = lastDate.AddDays(+1).ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "ddd M/d";
// Force redraw of chart
chart1.Update();
```

Comment: Post a picture showing what's wrong, and your code initializing the chart and filling it with data

Comment: [picture](http://i.imgur.com/XDGVFJM.png)